# How to know which element fire onclick event in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="myclick('000')" >
        <a href="#">Element 1</a>
    </li>
    <li onclick="myclick('001')" >
        <a href="#">Element 2</a>
    </li>
    <li onclick="myclick('002')" >
        <a href="#">Element 3</a>
    </li>
```

now i want to add selected class when li fire onClick event, is it possible through jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not jquery, You can just pass "this" in the myclick function to know the li

```
<li onclick="myclick('000', this)" >
```

Now in the myclick function second paramater will be the reference to the LI which fired the onlick event

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very much possible.

First of all you should use a jQuery binder for the click events and not the "onclick" method inline. You can do this as follows:

```
$("li").click(function(event){
    alert(event.target);
});
```

Here, the event.target property will tell you what HTML element was clicked.